# Reading a text file with dates into a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, text, import, date

I would like to read the following text file:

```
date        candy
1/12/2011   300
1/20/2010   200
1/16/2010   200
```

into a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
candysales= [ {'date': d(2011,1,12), 'sales': 300}, {'date': d(2010,1,20), 'sales': 200},{'date': d(2010,1,16), 'sales': 200}]
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how to begin doing this, or any resources that I can look at?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Like having a look at a [tuto](http://www.diveintopython.net/)?

Comment: Are the column headers relevant for the resulting dictionaries? The `"candy"` seems to be unused.

Comment: Looks like `csv` module can be used with space as delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`csv.DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) which will read a CSV file, using the first row as the dictionary key names, and parsing each row into a dictionary (you will lose field order in this case, as dictionaries are not reliably ordered). You can then convert the date from a string to a `datetime.date` object using [`datetime.datetime`'s `strptime` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), and the converting to a `date`:

```
candysales = []
for row in csv.DictReader(file('/path/to/sales.csv')):
    row['date'] = datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    candysales.append(row)
```

**Edit:** I've just noticed that the input isn't CSV (it looks like a fixed-width format). The `csv` module works with CSV files or tab-delimited files, but probably won't work well with this fixed-width format. If you can control the format of this file, CSV would be a good choice: if not, we can convert it using the `re` module:

```
def csvify(iterable):
    for line in utterable:
        yield re.sub('\s+', ',', line.rstrip())

candysales = []
for row in csv.DictReader(csvify(file('/path/to/sales.csv'))):
    row['date'] = datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    candysales.append(row)
```

The `csvify` function returns a generator which is passed to the `csv.DictReader`, which yields the lines from the underlying file by first replacing occurrences of one or more whitespace characters with a single comma, thus converting to CSV.

This probably won't serve as a general-purpose solution to converting fixed-width text formats to CSV, but it will work if the example you've given above is representative.

Answer (score 3):

You can read the entire file in a string

```
data = fin.read()
```

Split based on lines

```
data=data.splitlines()
```

Use List comprehension like

```
[dict((('date',datetime.datetime.strptime(k,"%m/%d/%Y")),('sales',v))) 
   for (k,v) in [e.split() for e  in data.splitlines()[1:]]]
```

which will give you a result like

```
[{'date': datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 12, 0, 0), 'sales': '300'}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 20, 0, 0), 'sales': '200'}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 16, 0, 0), 'sales': '200'}]
```

In case reading the entire file in memory is an issue for you, you can do the following

```
>>> candysales=[]
>>> fin.readline() # To Skip the First Line
for d in fin:
    k,v=d.split()
    candysales+=[dict((('date',datetime.datetime.strptime(k,"%m/%d/%Y")),('sales',v)))]
```

Comment: It would be more pythonic (and more efficient) to just iterate the file object. That yields lines with the line-ending on, unlike `splitlines`, so don't forget to use `rstrip()`.

Comment: @dcrosta. `rstrip()` would be redundant, because `split()` with no arguments does an implicit `strip()`.

Comment: @ekhumoro it's necessary if you do `for line in fin`, where each `line` will include the trailing line-ending

Comment: @dcrosta. Nope. `line.split()` will remove all leading and trailing whitespace before doing the split (as the second example in the above answer demonstrates).

Comment: @ekhumoro right, I'm saying that if you *don't* use `split` or `splitlines`, then you need to use `rstrip()` in order to get lines without line-endings. In other words: `[line for line in file('something.txt')] != [line for line in file('something.text').read().splitlines()]`.